# What are the possible causes of an infinite loop while using Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Recently I noticed that while testing my angular 2 app, it would completely freeze my computer to the point of not taking any input whatsoever. I want to avoid this but it's quite hard to test. What are some possible causes that I should be looking for?

Comment: Check your console while the tests are running.  I've crashed computers before by having `console.log` in an infinite loop.  Also, Angular may print some useful information if it's detecting an infinite loop.  If it only happens during tests and you can't duplicate it elsewhere, chances are the loop is in the tests.  You can narrow down which test by determining which only executed successfully (`console.error` may be helpful).  Even if it isn't within the test, you can narrow down where the loop is by looking at what the test is executing.

Comment: If narrowing down which test is causing the problem doesn't help, you may want to reconsider how you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

A function called from a components template that executes some non-trivial code.